# Azure account is not opening even after entering student email id

Tags: azure, azureportal

Azure account is not opening even after entering student email id

Your email domain is not currently registered with us. You can choose another verification method. this message is shown: [image]

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to an unmanaged AAD tenant issue and offer the following steps to sign up:

Open an InPrivate session of Internet Explorer and go to (https://imagine.microsoft.com/azure).
    Log in using your Microsoft Personal Account (if you don't have one, create it from http://signup.live.com).
    Complete the verification process using your Microsoft School Account address or activation code.
    Continue the activation of the Azure plan using the Microsoft Personal Account.

The steps above should still work even if you already tried to sign up using the Microsoft School Account and received the viral tenant error.

If the issue still persist, May I know what offer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your educational institute is not recognized/partnered or eligible with/for Microsoft.